# How to turn off USB chip permanently?

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, power-management

I am seeking ways to reduce power consumption on my raspberry pi 3B+. I've read that one of the most efficient ways is to turn off the USB chip. This [link](https://learn.pi-supply.com/make/how-to-save-power-on-your-raspberry-pi/) shows how to do so via the toggle commands.

Turn OFF USB chip

`echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind`

Turn ON USB chip

`echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind`

---

But I do not think that this is a permanent method, i.e. the USB chip turns on whenever I reboot the raspberry pi.

Is there a way to turn it off permanently?

Comment: That's the best you've got without physical destruction of the hardware.

Comment: I think I was looking more for adding a line of code into the `/boot/config.txt` , thats the way I've done it for switching off the LEDs and the HDMI port. Is the same method not possible for USB?

Comment: There's nothing like that. Create a systemd service to run your echo commands and get that started during boot-up.

Comment: doesn't turning off USB also turn off ethernet?

Comment: You can add `echo '1-1' |sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind` in `/etc/rc.local` befor `Exit 0`.

Comment: @M.Rostami Using `/etc/rc.local` is a very bad suggestion. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. The *@Tian* should follow the suggestion from *@Dougie* above.

Comment: @Ingo Yes, I've had a lot of bad experience with `/etc/rc.local`, however, It's ok when you wanna do an instant test. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually hardware is managed with options in `/boot/config.txt`. Available options can be found in `/boot/overlays/README`. I have searched there for `.*usb.*` without a match. So it seems there is no option for the kernel to disable the USB chip on boot up. You should use a systemd service to execute your command on boot up. Create a new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl --force --full edit turn_off_usb.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements:

```
[Unit]
Description=Turn off USB chip
After=basic.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'echo "1-1" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind'

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

Enable the new service with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable turn_off_usb.service
# check with
rpi ~$ systemctl status turn_off_usb.service
```